# Как задать размер Layout больше размера экрана?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Layout]

Возможно ли создать Layout границы которого изначально превышают размеры экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам разобрался. Был ограничен изначальным Layout, его и нужно было менять. `android:layout_height="3000dp"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3000dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Zone1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: У вас запросто может быть экран размером больше, чем 300dp, и ваш вариант не будет на нем больше размера экрана

Comment: @metalurgus 3000dp

Comment: Не досмотрел, да. Но все равно это костыль...

Comment: @metalurgus У вас есть другие предложениия?

Comment: Зависит от того, зачем это вам нужно

Comment: @metalurgus я задаю его большего размера для того что бы вложить определенное количество элементов. А затем весь этот layout прокрутить.

Comment: тем более - костыль. Положите ваш Layout в ScrollView, и не мучайтесь с его размером - выставьте высоту в  wrap_content

Comment: @metalurgus я думаю это не то что мне нужно. Дело в том что элементы представляют из себя например 20 кнопок, по 3 в ряде, они должны реагировать на нажатия во время движения. Список прокручивается автоматически.

Comment: Не понимаю. Можете подробно обьяснить? Зачем указывать высоту, если у вас будет список? Контент так же будет уезжать и приезжать